# IsExpanded Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, expander

I am quite new to XAML and WPF however I am trying the following.

I build a ListView with Expanders based on a groupDescription. Which works fine.
Now I am trying to bind the IsExpanded property to a item because if I switch tabs within my Application, the previous user made selection of expanded and collapsed expanders is deleted. Which means all Expanders a defaulted back to collapsed, which is quite annoying.

However I don't really understand how this should work. Can I just bind the IsExpanded Property of the Expander to a Property in my corresponding class? How will teh different groups be distinguished?

thank you very much

```
<ListView Name="Mails" local:FM.Register="{Binding}" local:FM.GetFocus="Loaded"
                  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MailsProxy.View}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedMail, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    local:SortList.BringIntoViewSelected="True" local:SortList.IsGridSortable="True"
                    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource InboxMailItem}"
                    View="{Binding Source={x:Static session:Session.Current}, Path=InboxView.View}">
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderStyle}">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <DockPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}, Path=DataContext.GroupBy}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14">:</TextBlock>
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Converter={StaticResource GroupHeaderConverter}}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                                </DockPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static session:Session.Current}, Path=InboxView}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Define some static bool variables and set properties for them and when user expand or collapse particular node then assign the respective value to boolean variables i.e isExpanded = Mails.Expanded and when u come back to the same tab again in the page render or page load check the value of static variable and assign the same value to the Mails.Expanded = isExpanded this will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you go a bit more into detail?

Answer (score -1):

Code would be like this.

```
static bool isExpanded = false;
```

I am considering Window1 is the name of the window into which the List View control is added

```
private void Window1_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Mails.Expanded = isExpanded;
    //... rest of your code
}

private void Mails_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    isExpaned = Mails.Expanded;
}
```

Hope this might clear your view.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this would only trigger all groups to be collapsed or expanded, not specific groups which are generated by the GroupDescription, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yeah i might be wrong but i just suggested you the solution you can make a static list of Expanded flags for each group and in Window_load you can retrieve those value back and assign them to each groups expanded property .. hope this might solve your problem and if further help required please ask for it

Comment: If u want me to give u working solution then I will require some amount of time is that ok with you ??

Comment: sure its okay for me. Im just stuck with this association between groups and expanded property

Comment: @Xeun Have u got the solution for this problem or do you need some more help ??